Medida não reconhece nenhuma coluna - Power BI
Ao tentar criar uma medida no power bi, a medida não reconhece as colunas da minha tabela, onde aparece o seguinte erro:
"O valor de ''indicacao_rca_validada'' não pode ser determinado. A coluna não existe ou não há, no momento, nenhuma linha para essa coluna."
porém, ao criar uma nova coluna, usando a mesma sintaxe, funciona normalmente:
% Indicacoes_Validadas = [indicacao_rca_validada] / [qtd_Indicacoes_RCA]
Poderia ter alguma configuração no Power BI que possa resolver esse problema?

Não duplique perguntas. Se precisar revisar algo faça na pergunta original clicando no link "editar" que fica abaixo da pergunta original. Comentários devem ser feitos na pergunta original, também.
